# Warning parser/current is loading parser/ruby22

Tags: ruby, parsing, rubygems

I'm newbie in Ruby, while excecuting a command I got this error.

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby22, which recognizes
warning: 2.2-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.3.1.
```

My Ruby version is 2.3.1
My parser version is 2.4.0.0.

I don't know why parser is loading from ruby22 which is not even installed in my computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What command are you running? From which gem in which version(s)? Does the command still work?

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1819

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was running an old version of Rubocop (which relies on the parser gem).  Removing/updating rubocop or whatever gem is using parser may fix your issue.